# Getting "invalid host header" while connecting to UI server, running on EC2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, nginx, webpack

I am running a UI application on EC2 instance. Please find below its devServer setting

```
devServer: {
      open: false,
      port: 3000,
      static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    }
```

I am able to connect UI using http://My_Public_IP:3000

But I am not able to connect with `test.mydomain.com`

I have setup `test.mydomain.com` using nginx ssl on EC2 with setting `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000`

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: I know it seems obvious, but you verified that `test.mydomain.com` resolves to `My_Public_IP`?

Comment: @Brettski What do you  mean by ` test.mydomain.com resolves to My_Public_IP`? Could you please guide me?

Comment: I am assuming that `test.mydomain.com` is setup in DNS to return the value of `My_Public_IP`. I am ensuring that the the two tests you are doing are working with the same values

Comment: server {

        server_name test.mydomain.com;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

Comment: above one is my nginx server block config. @Brettski Are there any command which you want me to verify?

Comment: if you run `nslookup test.mydomain.com` from a command line, does it return the same value as you are testing with (e.g. my_public_ip)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229614/discussion-between-ayush-mishra-and-brettski).

Comment: Yes @Brettski. It gives me same value. Even I just checked that I am able to connect UI using http://test.mydomain.com:3000/.

How can I remove port? I want "http://test.mydomain.com"  => "http://My_Public_IP:3000"


What should I do?  As you can see in above server block config, I am also giving proxy_pass as localhost:3000.

Please let me know what I Am missing.